# Vector of pointer declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, nullptr

Looking at some code my professor gave me and I don't understand what is happening. I am new to programming and completely lost.

```
vector <_Account*>*myvector = nullptr;
```

So I know he made a vector, and I know of an existing class called `Account` so is this a `vector` of pointers to an `Account` objects? and I don't know what the second asterisk does?

Comment: Looking at this question/example, you might want to invest in a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: [The spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) can be helpful for parsing complicated expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myvector` is a pointer to `vector` (most likely `std::vector` + the [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) `using namespace std;`) of pointers to `_Account`. No actual `vector` is created in this line, just a variable that can store the address of one.

`_Account` is an [implementation reserved identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) btw, it must not be used.

Comment: Really important point that last one. Observing the naming conventions of the language can save a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pointer to a vector of pointers to _Account (very badly named) class. To use the vector, it should either be allocated, or assigned to address of already existing vector of the same type. To use it's _Account elements, those elements in turn needs to be either allocated, or assigned to the addresses of existing _Account instances.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it down into two steps:

> typedef  vector<_Account*>    objectvector;
>
> objectvector   *myvector = nullptr;

1)  objectvector is a vector of pointers(of type _Account).

2)  myvector is a pointer to type objectvector.